# How to copy files with shutil.copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, shutil

I am scanning a folder & its subfolders for files which have a specific format like this: `saving_0.0000000.gz`. There are folders containing hundreds of these files, and I want to extract the file with the greatest numeric value in its name. For example, if in a folder I have `saving_0.0000000.gz`, `saving_100.00000.gz` and `saving_250.00000.gz`, I want the program to only copy the `saving_250.00000.gz` file.

The program I wrote seems to walk correctly the parent folder (with `os.walk`), and it finds the correct files (I checked with the debugger). So I store the name of the file I'm interested in (i.e. `saving_123456.78.gz`) in the `fichier` variable, but when I execute the program, it copies a lot more files than i need. I tried moving the `shutil.copy` out of the last for loop (so that it doesn't copy every file), but I get an error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/saving_0.0000000.gz'
```

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.4

import re, os, shutil, gzip

sauvegarde = '/mnt/desto/Sauvegardes_archivees'
dossier = '/mnt/desto/EPS2_900_V5/'
matrices = ['subfolder_1', 'subfolder_2', 'subfolder_3']

for mat in matrices:
    for folders, subfolders, files in os.walk(dossier + mat):
        fichier = 'saving_0.0000000.gz'
        for file in files:
            f = fichier.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
            if not file.startswith('saving_') or not file.endswith('.gz') or not len(file) == 19:
                continue
            hgz_sauv = file.split('_')[1]
            h_sauv = hgz_sauv.split('.')[0]
            if len(h_sauv) >= len(f) and int(h_sauv) >= int(f):
                fichier = file
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(dossier,mat,folders,fichier),sauvegarde)
```

Comment: your `shutil.copy` command is not indented within the `if` block . Is this from your code or just wrong indentation when copied over?

Comment: This is from my code. In the initial code, the shutil.copy was indented in the if block, but the result was the same. When it finds the folder containing the requested files, it compares them to each other, and stores the value in fichier in the if block. But since shutil.move is in the if block, it copies the file every time the condition is met. I want the program to copy just one file, after the for loop is finished in the respective folder

Comment: I guess the problem should be your files are unordered when you loop through them. So whichever comes out first will be moved. Try move your shutil copy command outside your `for file in files`.